# ¿Como ordeno un archivo de texto en forma descendente?

Tags: python

Hasta ahora he probado con estos ejemplos y no he podido resolverlo:

```
linea1=(open("ENDEUDADOS2.TXT"))
linea1.sort(reverse=False)
```

me sale error:

> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'sort'

con este:

```
linea1=("ENDEUDADOS2.TXT")
linea1.sorted(reverse=False)
```

error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sorted'

con este no me escribe nada en el archivo de salida:

```
linea1=sorted("ENDEUDADOS-FINAL.TXT",reverse=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
open("ENDEUDADOS2.TXT","w").writelines(linea1)
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, voy a suponer que quieres ordenar las líneas del archivo según **orden lexicográfico** (como cadenas), en caso contrario necesitarás aplicar el casting adecuado a cada línea antes de ordenar.

La causa de que no funcione te la dice el error en los dos primeros casos:

- En el primer código intentas usar el supuesto método `sort` de `linea1`, dónde `línea1` es 
  el archivo abierto, un objeto `_io.TextIOWrapper`  y que por tanto no tiene dicho método. Ten en cuenta que si se sigue las normas de estilo de Python `sort` es un método que actúa in-place por lo que solo estará definido, si lo está, para objetos mutables como las listas.
- En el segundo caso intentas usar el supuesto método `sorted` sobre una cadena (porque es solo eso, una cadena con el nombre o ruta de tu fichero). `str` tampoco tiene dicho método definido. [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) si que es una función preconstruida que acepta cualquier iterable y retorna una lista con los items ordenados.
- En el tercer caso, usas `sorted` correctamente sobre una cadena (no sobre tu fichero), por lo que al final escribirías en tu archivo la siguiente línea `XUTTSONNLIFEEDDDAA.-` que son los caracteres ordenados lexicográficamente de `"ENDEUDADOS-FINAL.TXT"` y esto cuando el GC cierre el archivo y se vacíe el buffer, ya que no cierras el fichero explícitamente y los cambios pueden no reflejarse por tanto de forma inmediata.

La solución simple es usar efectivamente el builtin `sorted` y pasarle el fichero (el cual es iterable gracias a `readline`). Es buena práctica cerrar siempre de forma explicita un fichero abierto con `open` mediante el método `close` o usar `with` que lo hará por ti:

```
with open("ENDEUDADOS.txt") as in_file, open("ENDEUDADOS2.TXT","w") as out_file:
    out_file.writelines(sorted(in_file, reverse=True))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla te comento, lo pude resolver de esta manera:

<pre>archivo = open("ENDEUDADOS-FINAL.TXT", "r")   
lineas  = archivo.readlines()
lineas.sort(reverse=True)
open("ENDEUDADOS2.TXT","w").writelines(lineas)  <code>


pero no se si es tan adecuado como tu método, ¿tu cual me recomiendas?

Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: disculpa pero no se como editar los comentarios

Comment: En terminos de memoria es lo mismo, ambas cargan el archivo al completo en memoria en una lista una sola vez (esto es necesario para TimSort).. `archivo.readlines()` crea una lista con todas la líneas del fichero y lo hace también iterando sobre el mismo mediante el método `readline` (la implementación en C del mismo realmente) igual que hace sorted (`newlist = PySequence_List(seq);`). En tiempo de ejecución las posibles diferencias son insignificantes, con `sorted` se ahorran unas cuantas lineas de bytecode (pero la diferencia no es significativa) y escribes menos código.

Comment: Eso si, como te recomiendo en la respuesta cierra de forma explícita los fichero o tarde o temprano te encontrarás con resultados inesperados, especialmente cuando los modificas.